# Extern variable names not visible in main?

Tags: c, scope, extern

[image]

I read it in C programming (Dennits M. Ritchie) and Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ew7daa.aspx), that 
Extern variables are not visible (cannot be accessed) in main.

This is confusing, as I have used following technique many times.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sp = 99; //extern variable
int main(){
 printf("sp is :%d",sp);     //not visible?
 sp = 98;
 printf("sp is :%d",sp); //ofcourse it is visible!
}
```

Comment: In the MSDN example, the globals are declared *after* the definition of `main`.

Comment: If `sp` is a variable defined in another source file that is linked with your program, you need to do `extern int sp = 99;`.  Then you should be able to access it in main.

Comment: I am specifically talking regarding the contents in book as shown in updated post with picture. Thanks.

Comment: Read that paragraph carefully, you are interpreting it wrong. It has nothing to do with externs, it has to with order of declaration. Externs or functions, or variables.

Comment: I still don't get it, let me try compiling some more sample codes.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your link has this code

```
int main() {}

int var = 0;
double val[MAXVAL];
char find( fileptr ) {}
int count( double f ) {}
```

And then proceeds to say var and val are not available in main. That is because they are
declared AFTER main.

It has nothing to do with extern variables. Only order of declaration.

---

Update. The photo is saying the exact same thing. The order in which they appear in the file determines their visibility.

The reason the variables are not visible in main has to do with the order in which they appear in the file. They come AFTER main.

The photo says, "The scope of an external variable or a function lasts from the point at which it is declared to the end of the file being compiler.".

It says nothing about extern variables not being visible in main.

Comment: But what does Author mean when he says "extern variables are not visible in main??"

Comment: I don't see that sentence in your link. In any event, main has the same visibility as any other function. Your quote seems blatantly false.